# How do I get all the badges in single web-service call by using Stack Exchange API?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm just trying to get all my **badges** of `StackOverflow` by using [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).

I tried below call request

[try1](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1114338/badges?order=desc&min=bronze%20&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow)

[try2](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1114338/badges?page=1&pagesize=80&order=desc&sort=type&site=stackoverflow)

But every time I'm unable to get all the **80 Badges** that I have in my Stack Overflow profile.

How do I get all the badges by using [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users#order=desc&min=bronze%20&sort=rank&ids=1114338&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get all **unique** badges. That is a total of 47, just as is shown in your profile.

Each badge type has an attribute `award_count`. If you sum these across the 47 badges you got in the `items` array you get the outcome of 80 like you expect.

The snippet shows a possible implementation and illustrates above text.

```js
function show() {
  
   document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = json.items.length;

   var awc = 0
   for(var i=0; i< json.items.length; i++) {
      awc += json.items[i].award_count;
   }

   document.getElementById('ac').innerHTML = awc;
}

var json = {
 "items" : [{
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 276,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/276/java",
   "name" : "java"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 291,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/291/android",
   "name" : "android"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 395,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/395/listview",
   "name" : "listview"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 549,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/549/google-maps",
   "name" : "google-maps"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 678,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/678/sqlite",
   "name" : "sqlite"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "gold",
   "badge_id" : 178,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/178/android",
   "name" : "android"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 1544,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1544/android-fragments",
   "name" : "android-fragments"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "tag_based",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 151,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/151/android",
   "name" : "android"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "gold",
   "badge_id" : 155,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate",
   "name" : "Electorate"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 2,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 1973,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus",
   "name" : "Caucus"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 1974,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent",
   "name" : "Constituent"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 6,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 2278,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/2278/custodian",
   "name" : "Custodian"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 2600,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/2600/informed",
   "name" : "Informed"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 4368,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/4368/explainer",
   "name" : "Explainer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 220,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/220/promoter",
   "name" : "Promoter"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 221,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor",
   "name" : "Benefactor"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 225,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious",
   "name" : "Tenacious"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "gold",
   "badge_id" : 226,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero",
   "name" : "Unsung Hero"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 804,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/804/suffrage",
   "name" : "Suffrage"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 884,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/884/talkative",
   "name" : "Talkative"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 900,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum",
   "name" : "Quorum"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 1108,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1108/vox-populi",
   "name" : "Vox Populi"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 1276,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader",
   "name" : "Proofreader"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 3,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 1478,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer",
   "name" : "Reviewer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 1,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1/teacher",
   "name" : "Teacher"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 2,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/2/student",
   "name" : "Student"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 3,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor",
   "name" : "Editor"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 5,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer",
   "name" : "Organizer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 6,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/6/supporter",
   "name" : "Supporter"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 7,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic",
   "name" : "Critic"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 8,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol",
   "name" : "Citizen Patrol"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 9,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer",
   "name" : "Autobiographer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 10,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/10/scholar",
   "name" : "Scholar"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 12,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white",
   "name" : "Strunk &amp; White"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 3,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 13,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling",
   "name" : "Yearling"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 14,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner",
   "name" : "Self-Learner"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 6,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 19,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened",
   "name" : "Enlightened"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 10,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 23,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer",
   "name" : "Nice Answer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 4,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 24,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/24/good-answer",
   "name" : "Good Answer"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 6,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 26,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question",
   "name" : "Popular Question"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 2,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 27,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question",
   "name" : "Notable Question"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 31,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator",
   "name" : "Commentator"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 32,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty",
   "name" : "Civic Duty"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 63,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed",
   "name" : "Tumbleweed"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 71,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/enthusiast",
   "name" : "Enthusiast"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "silver",
   "badge_id" : 94,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit",
   "name" : "Pundit"
  }, {
   "user" : {
    "reputation" : 23696,
    "user_id" : 1114338,
    "user_type" : "registered",
    "accept_rate" : 100,
    "profile_image" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6GG.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name" : "M D",
    "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d"
   },
   "badge_type" : "named",
   "award_count" : 1,
   "rank" : "bronze",
   "badge_id" : 144,
   "link" : "http://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard",
   "name" : "Mortarboard"
  }
 ],
 "has_more" : false,
 "quota_max" : 300,
 "quota_remaining" : 298
};

show();
```

```html
unique badges <br />
<div id="x">
  </div>

<div>
  Total badges awarded
  <div id="ac">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: profile showing relation between unique badges and award_count]

Comment: Ya your're absolutely right. @rene Thanks.